# ItemTemplate for Point3D items

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have a widget where I want to render a Point3D as a "floating bubble with label inside" whose position is determined by X and Y properties, and label text determined by Z value.

I don't know how I should data-bind Z property of Point3D to Text property of a TextBlock, since Z is not a dependency property.

My current non-working code (although properly rendering the fallback value) is as follows:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="Point3D">
        <Border 
            Width="20"
            Height="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Background="white" BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CorLinhaSimetria}"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="-10" Y="-10"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>

            <!-- Critical part here -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Z, FallbackValue=0°}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>             
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Z` is `DependancyProperty` as long as `TextBlock.Text` is. Therefore `Text="{Binding Z ...}"` should work and initial `Z` value should display.

Comment: Currently I found a somewhat awkward solution of binding to the point itself, using a converter to get a formatted string from its Z property...

Comment: But if converter in the same binding has access to `Z` then it should also display without converter. What exactly is not working in the code above? Does it always show `FallbackValue`?

Comment: Well, I've made a bunch of changes already, gonna have to confirm it tomorrow (now that you said it, I have the impression of a "white text over white background" effect... :/